# DateTime to TimeSpan from FileTime epoch?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Given the code

```
var dt = new DateTime(2015, 5, 6);
var ts = dt.Subtract(new DateTime(1601, 1, 1));
```

Considering in this code there is a subtract of a `new DateTime(1601, 1, 1)` which is the epoch for Windows FileTime, is there a better way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: i'm confused. there's no such thing as the absolute timespan of a datetime. there is only a timespan between two datetimes.

Comment: what is an absolute TimeSpan of a DateTime variable?

Comment: Are you looking for the `DateTime.Ticks` property?

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad. excuse me.

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "this is not a proper base" - or what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: @codiac what is the actual question? What are you trying to do? What do you mean by `absolute TimeSpan`? And how is that different from DateTime itself? Today *is* 2017 years, 11 months, 8 days etc after the "base"

Comment: When I convert with DateTime.FromFileTime the year starts from year 1601 (which I called the base). So probably not the best way I have asked the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Well, it's 2016 years, 10 months and 7 days after `DateTime.MinValue`. But years and months aren't precise measures of time anyway - that's more like a Period (in Noda Time / java.time / jodatime terminology) than a TimeSpan (Duration in Noda Time etc terminology)

Comment: @codiac: When you convert *what* with DateTime.FromFileTime? Fundamentally your question is really unclear in terms of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps the information that you are looking for can be found in [DateTime.FromFileTime(Int64) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletime?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTime_FromFileTime_System_Int64_)?

Comment: @codiac Please add an example of what you want the result of this whole thing to look like.

Comment: @codiac if you use `FromFileTime` it means you already have a file time value. You can use the `TimeSpan(long)` constructor to get a time span

Comment: Sorry all for bad question. It got confusing as it was confusing for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally a `DateTime` is represented as an offset from an epoch measured in ticks (100 ns intervals). While your question is not being entirely clear it seems that you want this offset as a `TimeSpan` (which can be used to represent an offset measured in ticks).

The `DateTime` epoch is `0001-01-01` (`DateTime.MinValue`). However, you use `1601-01-01`. This is the epoch of a Windows file time so to get the same `TimeSpan` as you ask for you can do the following:

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
```

Comment: Or just `new TimeSpan(theOriginalFileTimeValue)`. According to the docs, both TimeSpan and file time work with 100ns intervals

Comment: @Martin Liversage and Panagiotis Kanavos Thank You both. This is the answer I was hoping for. Got confusing for me too with two different epochs.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what the actual question is, so here is my guess: How to convert a file time tick value to a TimeSpan.

Windows File time is the number of 100ns intervals since 1600-01-01. A TimeSpan is a wrapper aroung ticks, ie 100ns intervals. You can use the [TimeSpan(Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor to create a TimeSpan object from a file time tick value:

```
var ts= new TimeSpan(ticks);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Panagiotis Kanavos noted, maybe you want to use this?

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(fileTime);
```

Or maybe you want to subtract `DateTime.FromFileTime(0)` like so?

```
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.FromFileTime(0));
```

Or maybe you are searching for the `Duration` method?

If your TimeSpan value is negative, it will provide an absolute value as a TimeSpan instance, like in the following example.

```
var format = "{0,22}{1,22}{2,22}";
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1601, 1, 1));

Console.Write("TimeSpan: ");
Console.WriteLine(format, timeSpan);
Console.Write("Duration:  ");
Console.WriteLine(format, timeSpan.Duration());

/* Console Output  ------------------
TimeSpan: -00:00:00.1234567
Duration:  00:00:00.1234567
------------------ ------------------ */
```

Comment: Actually, `Duration()` returns an instance of TimeSpan. I edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Why do you think the Duration method is relevant to what the OP wants at all? Fundamentally, I think the question is too unclear to answer at the moment. I'd wait until it's clarified rather than guessing.

Comment: By definition, duration returns the "the absolute value of the current TimeSpan object". And he asked for an sbsolute TimeSpan.

Comment: I strongly suspect the OP wasn't using "absolute" in terms of "non-negative" but as "anchored to an epoch". There's nothing in the question about negative timespans.

Comment: In the meantime, this has become clear. There was a lot of missing information in the original question. I tried to help the OP in my spare time and guessed a few times. And if someone googles this page, he might be searching for the absolute value, meaning positive value. Comments could not transport all the meaning of my suggestions.